# Can I get the schema name in changelog file when I add new changeset(sql query)?

Tags: sql, maven, liquibase

When I add

```
defaultSchemaName:myDB
```

in my properties file, I can get schema name like this:

```
UPDATE MYDB.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK....
INSERT INTO MYDB.DATABASECHANGELOG....
UPDATE MYDB.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK...
```

But if I add new changeset to my sql file like this

```
--changeset
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE;
```

I can't get schema name. My result is:

```
UPDATE MYDB.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK....
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE;
INSERT INTO MYDB.DATABASECHANGELOG....
UPDATE MYDB.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK...
```

My question is, is there any way to add schema name to my new query like the others?

```
SELECT * FROM MYDB.MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

The properties file is handled by liquibase for its own changeset.
When you write SQL statement, liquibase execute them directly to the database.

You can handle this by defining a default database in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify your sql files (if you are using sqlfiles) and use placeholders. So for example you will have changeset like this:

```
--changeset
SELECT * FROM ${mySchema}MYTABLE;
```

I guess that best practise for this is to define property in main changelog like this (you can define it empty or predefined with your schema):

```
<property name="mySchema" value="" />
```

and then in runtime pass it like parameter from command line (`-Dparameter.mySchema=MYDB.` note: I'm not sure here if it should be prefixed with `parameter`, in liquibase.properties it must be) or put it into `liquibase.properties`.